# Why does this datetime.datetime.strptime example not work?

Tags: python, datetime

This seems very straightforward, and yet I can't figure out why it's failing:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('Thu Feb 09 12:18:29 2012', '%a %b %d %X %Y')
```

fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Thu Feb 09 12:18:29 2012' does not match format '%a %b %d %X %Y'
```

As far as I can tell from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), this is a perfectly accurate usage of the function. What am I missing? I am running Python 2.7.

Comment: it provides no error for me in 2.7.11

Comment: Works fine for me in 2.7.12

Comment: Works for me in both 2.7.13 and 3.6.0

Comment: Huh. Okay, I guess I'll restart my system. Strange.

Comment: Don't you love the speeeeeeeeeeeed of the feedback

Comment: @bernie yes. Haha